# sed/awk insert line between 2 matches but only if there is not an other pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

In order to write an script for an automated installation and configuration of Fail2Ban i need a way to modify a /etc/fail2ban/jail.local. My problem is, that i need to add a line in an specific section of the file, but only if the pattern `enabled = true` does not exist within the area. There are other areas where it shouldn’t write `enable = true`.

The following seds work fine, but do not check if there is already the `enabled = true` :

```
sed '/\[apache-auth\]/{x;s/.*/./;x};/port/{x;/^.$/{x;s/^/enabled = true\n/;x};s/^/./;x}' -i /etc/fail2ban/jail.local 
sed '/\[apache-badbots\]/{x;s/.*/./;x};/port/{x;/^.$/{x;s/^/enabled = true\n/;x};s/^/./;x}' -i /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
sed '/\[apache-noscript\]/{x;s/.*/./;x};/port/{x;/^.$/{x;s/^/enabled = true\n/;x};s/^/./;x}' -i /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
sed '/^\[sshd\]/{x;s/.*/./;x};/port/{x;/^.$/{x;s/^/enabled = true\n/;x};s/^/./;x}' -i /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

**Update adding requested information**

**original file**

```
[sshd]

port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = %(sshd_backend)s

[apache-auth]

port     = http,https
logpath  = %(apache_error_log)s


[apache-badbots]
# Ban hosts which agent identifies spammer robots crawling the web
# for email addresses. The mail outputs are buffered.
port     = http,https
logpath  = %(apache_access_log)s
bantime  = 172800
maxretry = 1


[apache-noscript]

port     = http,https
logpath  = %(apache_error_log)s
```

**expected output**

```
[sshd]

enabled = true
port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = %(sshd_backend)s
#
# HTTP servers
#

[apache-auth]

enabled = true
port     = http,https
logpath  = %(apache_error_log)s


[apache-badbots]
# Ban hosts which agent identifies spammer robots crawling the web
# for email addresses. The mail outputs are buffered.
enabled = true
port     = http,https
logpath  = %(apache_access_log)s
bantime  = 172800
maxretry = 1


[apache-noscript]

enabled = true
port     = http,https
logpath  = %(apache_error_log)s
```

*English is not my native, so please don't judge my spelling errors. I am also not sure, if this is the correct site for this Question.*

Comment: Can you please paste input and expected output file.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR i added the inputfile and the desired output

Comment: If you get the sample down to, say 15 lines instead of 50 or whatever that is then you'll have a lot more people interested in looking at your question since it'll take them far less time to understand your requirements. Any time you need a scrollbar in either direction your sample is too big and you should try again to create a [mcve] (note **Minimal**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/^\[(apache-(auth|loadbots|noscript)|sshd)\]/{:a;x;/./!bb;/enabled = true/!s/^\w/enabled = true\n&/M;p;:b;x;h;d};H;$ba;d' file
```

This stores the section in the hold space, inserts `enabled = true` if it does not already exist and prints out the section.

In detail:

The [command line switches](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options) `-r` and `-n` are activated, which allows regexps to be more easily expressed for the former and optional printing (grep-like i.e. the commands `p` or `P` must be present) for the latter.

The command consists of an if-then-else.

If the current line begins with `[` and encloses one of four words, followed by `]`, the commands between `{` and `}` will be enacted.

The first command following the opening `{` is a place holder, used when the end-of-file condition is met.

The `x` means switch the pattern space (PS) with the hold space (HS). Sed has [two registers](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Execution-Cycle), the PS is where the current line (minus its newline) read into. The HS is a spare register, to be used at the programmers discretion.

The next command `/./!bb` checks to see if the HS is empty (which will be if this is the first time this code has been executed) and if so jumps to the `:b` name space, missing out the following code.

Now that it is known that HS contains one or more lines, these lines are checked to see if they contain the string `enabled = true` and if not, the string `enabled = true` is inserted infront of the first line that begins with a word character.

Regardless of the match or non-match the HS is printed with `p` command.

The branch name space is now encounted `:b` and the HS and PS are exchanged, the current line replaces whatever is in the HS `h` and then deleted `d`, which ends the processing of that line.

If the first regexp failed: the current line is appended to the HS `H` and deleted `d` unless it was the last line in which case the processing is directed to the name space `:a` by the command `$ba`. This covers off the end-of-file condition in which lines in the HS will need to be processes as above.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but unfortunately it insert at all sections, not just those which should be enabled. it seem I cut a bit to much out of the files in order to create an minimal example;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you add an explanation what this string is doing exactly? Since I am a beginner, i don't understand all

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -v sections='sshd apache-auth apache-badbots apache-noscript' -v RS= -v ORS="\n\n" '
     BEGIN     {n=split(sections,a); 
                for(i=1; i<=n; i++) sec["["a[i]"]"]} 
     $1 in sec {$2 = "\nenabled = true\n"}1' file
```

maintains the tags in the sections variable, and inserts the required line for the corresponding sections.  Expects the section headers to be the only entry on the line.